# How do I autowire a field with a real implementation while mocking another field?

Tags: junit, spring-boot, mockito

I'm trying to unit test a Spring-boot controller and one of my `@Autowired` fields is coming back null.

I have two autowired fields in this controller:

```
public class UserProfileController{

@Autowired
private UserProfileService profileService;

@Autowired
private IDataValidator dataValidatorImpl;
```

My test class is as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = UserProfileServiceApplication.class)
public class ControllerTest {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Mock
UserProfileService profileServiceMock;

@Autowired
ApplicationContext actx;

@InjectMocks
private UserProfileController profileController;

@Before
public void setup() {
// Process mock annotations
String[] asdf = actx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
for (int i = 0; i < asdf.length; i++){
System.out.println(asdf[i]);
}

MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

// Setup Spring test in standalone mode
this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(profileController).build();

}

/**
* All this does is verify that we return the correct datatype and HTTP status
* @throws Exception
*/
@Test
public void testGetProfileSuccess() throws Exception {
Mockito.when(profileServiceMock.getProfile(Mockito.any(HashMap.class))).thenReturn(new HashMap<String, Object>());

mockMvc.perform(get("http://localhost:8095/UserName?tenantId=tenant1"))
.andExpect(status().isOk())
.andExpect(content().contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));

//verify profileService was only used once
Mockito.verify(profileServiceMock, Mockito.times(1)).getProfile(Mockito.any(HashMap.class));

//verify we're done interacting with profile service
Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(profileServiceMock);
}
```

If I leave IDataValidator untouched in the test class, it comes up null and I get a NPE. If I `@Spy` the DataValidatorImpl, it cannot find properties from the Spring environment that it needs to work.

How can I just let the IDataValidator autowire itself and maintain its spring environment context as if I were just running the application normally?

When I print all beans in my `@Before` setup() method, I can see DataValidationImpl in the list.

Comment: Where are you mocking `IDataValidator`?

Comment: I'm trying not to mock it. When I was using the `@spy` annotation, see edit above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I swear I did this the first time but when trying to recreate the error thrown for jny it actually worked.

My solution is to inject via `@Spy` annotation and get the bean from the `ApplicationContext` in my `@Before` setup method.

```
public class ControllerTest {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Mock
UserProfileService profileServiceMock;

@Spy
IDataValidator dataValidator;

@Autowired
ApplicationContext actx;

@InjectMocks
private UserProfileController profileController;

@Before
public void setup() {

dataValidator = (IDataValidator) actx.getBean("dataValidatorImpl");

MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

// Setup Spring test in standalone mode
this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(profileController).build();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you mock your controller with

```
MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(profileController).build();
```

the controller is replaced in the context. Since you did not inject any `IDataValidator` in it, it is null.

The simplest solution is to autowired the real `IDataValidator` into your test class and inject it into the controller.

In your controller:

```
public class UserProfileController{

private UserProfileService profileService;
private IDataValidator dataValidatorImpl;

@Autowired
public UserProfileController(UserProfileService profileService, IDataValidator dataValidatorImpl) {
   this.profileService = profileService;
   this.dataValidatorImpl = dataValidatorImpl;
}
```

And in your test :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = UserProfileServiceApplication.class)
public class ControllerTest {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

private UserProfileService profileService;

@Autowired
private IDataValidator dataValidator;

@Before
public void setup() {
    UserProfileService profileService = Mockito.mock(UserProfileService.class);
    UserProfileController controller = new UserProfileController(profileService, dataValidator);

   // Setup Spring test in standalone mode
   this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to inject `UserProfileController` with real Validator and mock Service.

In this case I suggest to use `@ContextConfiguration` annotaion which allows to configure context in the test. You'll need to create a Configuration class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = UserProfileServiceApplication.class)
public class ControllerTest {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Mock
UserProfileService profileServiceMock;

@Autowired
ApplicationContext actx;

//comment this line out
//@InjectMocks
@Autowired
private UserProfileController profileController;

@Before
public void setup() {
// Process mock annotations
String[] asdf = actx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
for (int i = 0; i < asdf.length; i++){
System.out.println(asdf[i]);
}

//comment this line out
//MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

  @Configuration
  public static class Config {

    //wire validator - if it is not wired by other configurations
    @Bean
    Validator validator() {
        return new Validaor();
    }

    //wire mock service
    @Bean
    public UserProfileService profileService() {
        return mock(UserProfileService.class);
    }
}
```